# Not "\u": How to Unescape Unicode in JSON?

Tags: python, json, unicode, encoding, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape from a non-English website using Scrapy. The scraped results as JSON look something like this:

```
{"price": "13,000", "name": "\u58c1\u6bb4\u308a\u4ee3\u884c\u69d8\u5c02\u7528\u2605 \u30c6\u30ec\u30d3\u672c\u4f53 20v\u578b \u767d \u9001\u6599\u8fbc"},
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//section[@class="items-box"]'):
      item = ShopItem()
      item['name'] = sel.xpath('a/div/h3/text()').extract()
      item['price'] = sel.xpath('a/div/div/div[1]/text()').extract().replace("$", "")
      yield item
```

How would I output unescaped Unicode characters onto the JSON?

Comment: There was an issue the other day about just this: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1963. Check how to use a [custom items exporter](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1963#issuecomment-215797219) **without** `ensure_ascii=True` (the default with scrapy)

Comment: The example is valid json (almost - it has a comma at the end) and could be converted to python with `json.loads`. But your question is still very confusing. Where is this json exactly? Is it embedded in an html page? If `name` is in the json, how would it also be accessed with the `'a/div/h3/text()'` xpath?

Comment: @tdelaney The json is outputted by adding the `-o` option to `scrapy crawl spider`

Answer (score 7):

**Edit** (2016-10-19):

With Scrapy 1.2+, you can use the [`FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#std:setting-FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING) set to the character encoding you need for the output JSON file, e.g `FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = 'utf-8'` (the default value being `None`, which means `\uXXXX` escaping)

---

Note: I'm adapting [what I wrote on GitHub for a similar issue](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1963#issuecomment-215784229) I linked to in the question's comments.

Note that there's an open issue on Scrapy to make the output encoding a parameter: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1965

---

[Scrapy's default JSON exporter](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/ebef6d7c6dd8922210db8a4a44f48fe27ee0cd16/scrapy/utils/serialize.py#L11) uses (the default) `ensure_ascii=True` argument, so it outputs Unicode characters as `\uXXXX` sequences before writing to file. (This is what is used when doing `-o somefile.json`)

Setting `ensure_ascii=False` in the exporter will output Unicode strings, [which will end up as UTF-8 encoded on file](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/cf716ea200b4e7056a570434b8ab46a61aa20240/scrapy/exporters.py#L114). See custom exporter code at the bottom here.

To illustrate, let's read your input JSON string back into some data to work on:

```
>>> import json
>>> test = r'''{"price": "13,000", "name": "\u58c1\u6bb4\u308a\u4ee3\u884c\u69d8\u5c02\u7528\u2605 \u30c6\u30ec\u30d3\u672c\u4f53 20v\u578b \u767d \u9001\u6599\u8fbc"}'''
>>> json.loads(test)
{u'price': u'13,000', u'name': u'\u58c1\u6bb4\u308a\u4ee3\u884c\u69d8\u5c02\u7528\u2605 \u30c6\u30ec\u30d3\u672c\u4f53 20v\u578b \u767d \u9001\u6599\u8fbc'}
```

The input with `\uXXXX` sequences is valid JSON for Python (as it should), and `loads()` produces a valid Python `dict`.

Now let's serialize to JSON again:

```
>>> # dumping the dict back to JSON, with default ensure_ascii=True
>>> json.dumps(json.loads(test))
'{"price": "13,000", "name": "\\u58c1\\u6bb4\\u308a\\u4ee3\\u884c\\u69d8\\u5c02\\u7528\\u2605 \\u30c6\\u30ec\\u30d3\\u672c\\u4f53 20v\\u578b \\u767d \\u9001\\u6599\\u8fbc"}'
>>>
```

And now with `ensure_ascii=False`

```
>>> # now dumping with ensure_ascii=False, you get a Unicode string
>>> json.dumps(json.loads(test), ensure_ascii=False)
u'{"price": "13,000", "name": "\u58c1\u6bb4\u308a\u4ee3\u884c\u69d8\u5c02\u7528\u2605 \u30c6\u30ec\u30d3\u672c\u4f53 20v\u578b \u767d \u9001\u6599\u8fbc"}'
>>>
```

Let's print to see the difference:

```
>>> print json.dumps(json.loads(test))
{"price": "13,000", "name": "\u58c1\u6bb4\u308a\u4ee3\u884c\u69d8\u5c02\u7528\u2605 \u30c6\u30ec\u30d3\u672c\u4f53 20v\u578b \u767d \u9001\u6599\u8fbc"}

>>> print json.dumps(json.loads(test), ensure_ascii=False)
{"price": "13,000", "name": "壁殴り代行様専用★ テレビ本体 20v型 白 送料込"}
```

If you want to write JSON items as UTF-8, you can do it like this:

1.. define a custom item exporter, e.g. in an `exporters.py` file in your project

```
$ cat myproject/exporters.py 
from scrapy.exporters import JsonItemExporter


class Utf8JsonItemExporter(JsonItemExporter):

    def __init__(self, file, **kwargs):
        super(Utf8JsonItemExporter, self).__init__(
            file, ensure_ascii=False, **kwargs)
```

2.. replace the default JSON item exporter in your `settings.py`

```
FEED_EXPORTERS = {
    'json': 'myproject.exporters.Utf8JsonItemExporter',
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [the `codecs` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings) for [text -> text decoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings) (In Python 2 it's not strictly necessary, but in Python 3 `str` doesn't have a `decode` method, because the methods are for `str` -> `bytes` and back, not `str` -> `str`). Using the `unicode_escape` codec for decoding will get you the correct data back:

```
import codecs

somestr = codecs.decode(strwithescapes, 'unicode-escape')
```

So to fix the names you're getting, you'd do:

```
item['name'] = codecs.decode(sel.xpath('a/div/h3/text()').extract(), 'unicode-escape')
```

If the problem is in JSON you're producing, you'd want to just make sure the `json` module isn't forcing strings to be ASCII with character encodings; it does so by default because not all JSON parsers can handle true Unicode characters (they often assume data is sent as ASCII bytes with escapes). So wherever you call `json.dump`/`json.dumps` (or create a `json.JSONEncoder`), make sure to explicitly pass `ensure_ascii=False`.

Comment: `\uXXXX` encoding is valid for JSON. OP already has a valid JSON string and there is no need to do a unicode-escape. `json.loads` will convert the string to python.

Comment: @tdelaney: Agreed it's valid, but it's also perfectly reasonable to want to avoid doing so, either because the receiver is not a proper JSON parser (many implementations omit parts of the spec, or it's not even a proper JSON parser because some jerk rolled their own parsing code), or to reduce size (typically JSON is UTF-8 encoded, and UTF-8 for non-ASCII characters will be 2-4 bytes, usually 3 for East Asian languages, vs. a fixed 6 bytes for the ASCII escape code). It looks like the OP may be using JSON to format data scraped and organized in their script, not parsing JSON from the site.

Comment: @tdelaney: I think the idea is that they're parsing XML/HTML to pull specific bits of data out, then storing them in some object that they can JSON encode (which makes it easier to use or transmit later, avoiding XML/HTML parsing costs). So the HTML has these escapes in it, and they end up in the JSON encoded output (or they're not using `ensure_ascii=False` and the JSON encoding is creating them), so my approaches cover both sides; removing the encoding from the data pulled from the HTML and avoiding readding it on JSON serialization.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. if the text node at `a/div/h3/text()` is literally `\u58c1\u6bb4\u308a\u4ee3\u884c\u69d8\u5c02...`, then unicode-escape makes sense. You may have to unescape XML entities also. But if that's the case, why didn't OP say so?!

Comment: Upon implementing the suggestion by @ShadowRanger, the following error occurred: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-18: ordinal not in range(128)` Also @tdelaney, I'm quite a noob and can't figure what you're saying about XML entities? I prefer to unescape for the sake of legibility.

Comment: @ric.row: I can't reproduce, but if you're on Python 2, it might be an issue with using a text->text decoding on a `str` that will result in non-ASCII values. Would be fixable by decoding to `unicode` first, then doing text->text translation. Something like `codecs.decode(sel.xpath('a/div/h3/text()').extract().decode('ascii'), 'unicode-escape')`. Might be a problem representing non-ASCII in your terminal, or you might already have it decoded, and the text doesn't have `\u` escapes in it, it's just being printed using them because the Chinese(?) characters can't be shown in your locale.